# PHP variable error/file_put_contents error

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, file-put-contents

I am trying to use the file_put_contents() to create user specific pages. When a user first enters their account, I want the site to create a page that is accessible only by the user at mydomain.com/users/username.php. If they are not the user, then I am trying to redirect them to their own account page (because the users/username.html contains sensitive info). As such, I use this code in the username.html:

```
<?php 
$actual_link='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$net = $actual_link['filename']; 
if($_SESSION['username']==$net){
 echo 'Verified'; 
 } 
 else{ 
 header('Location:mydomain.com/user/welcome.php');
 } 
?>
```

This, hypothetically, would keep unauthorized users off of the page. To create the page for each user (and keep it scalable), I used

```
file_put_contents($urlphp,$phpstuff)
```

(I decided not use FILE_APPEND because the file shouldn't exist). $urlphp is the username ($_SESSION['username']) combined with .php, and $phpstuff is all of teh  that I put above. This is where I think I went wrong. I typed:

```
$phpstuff = "<?php 
$actual_link='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$net = $actual_link['filename']; 
if($_SESSION['username']==$net){
 echo 'Verified'; 
 } 
 else{ 
 header('Location:mydomain.com/user/welcome.php');
 } 
?>"
```

However, this code produced:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in path/to/users/welcome.php on line 35
```

Line 35 is:

```
$actual_link='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

However, (and keep in mind here, I'm relatively new to PHP/MySQL, so I'm going off of what I know and what PHP.net and W3Schools tell me) I couldn't find any whitespace in line 35. So I assumed that you can't have a multi-line variable (which wouldn't be detrimental to the code. I think....), so I tried making it all one line, which produced the exact same error, but moved the problematic line up one.

What I can't figure out is if it's a problem with my use of file_put_contents() or my use of the variable $phpstuff. If there is anything that I missed, please point it out, I am almost positive it is something that I'm overlooking. I am at a loss as to what to do/try. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what does the question have to do with mysql? there's no code to support it and what are you trying to do in `$phpstuff = "<?php ... ?>"` ?

Comment: *"As such, I use this code in the `username.html`"* - Did you instruct your server to treat it as php? *"I used

`file_put_contents($urlphp,$phpstuff)`"* - I don't see those variables defined anywhere. Your question's way too unclear.

Comment: I can only offer comments; see the answer given.

Comment: $urlphp and $phpstuff were defined right after the file_put_contents() code section.

Comment: $phpstuff would be PHP code given to the new page. I know, it's not very efficient or easy, but it's the best that I know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it this way.

Instead of generating PHP dynamically and creating a file for each separate user (which is wrong in so many ways), have one file that handles all users, and then pass the username / userid as a parameter to the script.

You could use .htaccess to route all requests for /users/*.php to, /users/index.php?user=*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I use the .htaccess to do that? Or do you have any links to explanations?

Comment: The following is a good "cheat sheet" for .htaccess: http://htaccesscheatsheet.com/

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I am relatively new to PHP/.htaccess. Which part of that site should I use for my needs?

Comment: You would probably want to place the the file in root of your public webserver files (same directory as domain.com/index.html or domain.com/index.php).

Comment: Ok and which part of the htaccesscheatsheet.com has what I need? I couldn't tell from the Table of Contents. Thank you again for all of your help. @enstage

Comment: Any PHP development framework has a robust routing system that handles this for you, so it's worth considering one of those or at least looking at what rules they inject into the configuration. Most handle all requests through a singular, stub `index.php`.